# Parse .ini sections with python-decouple

Tags: python-3.x, ini, decoupling, python-decouple

[Documentation](https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple) has a paradigm where the only section is called ***settings***
This seems to be the default namespace for *python-decouple* thus if you have:

```
[settings]
DEBUG=True
```

you can parse the config with:

```
from decouple import config
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)  # no section argument
```

But what if we have custom sections like:

```
[sectionA]
DEBUG=True

[sectionB]
foo="bar"
```

?

I know that one can easily use *ConfigParser* to parse custom sections, like so:

```
config_parser.get('sectionA', 'DEBUG')   # the corresponding call in ConfigParser
```

but I was wondering how it's done through *python-decouple* since it also supports *.ini* files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

section seems to be hardcoded as a class attribute in the [code](https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple/blob/master/decouple.py#L103), thus I suppose that there isn't any clean, parameterized solution to this issue.

```
class RepositoryIni(RepositoryEmpty):
    """
    Retrieves option keys from .ini files.
    """
    SECTION = 'settings'

    def __init__(self, source):
        self.parser = ConfigParser()
        with open(source) as file_:
            self.parser.readfp(file_)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return (key in os.environ or
                self.parser.has_option(self.SECTION, key))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.parser.get(self.SECTION, key)
```